# passing function value in laravel query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to passing function values in laravel query.I have a function `getUser` which returns `$val=['nithya.sreeraman','jaivignesh.parthiban','aadhil.ahmed','aarthe.sathyanaraya','abdulamjad.babu','khaja.hussain']`

```
function getUser() {
 $reportees=array();
 try{
 global $reportee_list;
 global $reportees; 
 /*stuff*/ 
  return $reportees;
 }
 catch{
 }
}
$val=getUser();
// print_r($val); 
 $program=DB::table('project')->whereIN('owner',$val)->pluck('project.name','project.code'); //I want to pass  $val in this query
```

I'm getting error

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

while passing $val.but executed when I pass as

```
 $program=DB::table('project')->whereIN('owner',['nithya.sreeraman','jaivignesh.parthiban','aadhil.ahmed','aarthe.sathyanaraya','abdulamjad.babu','khaja.hussain'])->pluck('project.name','project.code');
```

how to pass function value in laravel query.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot of info here, but it seems most likely that the return value from getUser() isn't actually an array, which is why whereIN() is throwing the error.

Double check that you're getting an array from getUser(). This is a bit clunky, but quick....

```
$val=getUser();
echo('Is array: ' . is_array($val));
```

If it is an array you'll get

> Is array: 1

and if it isn't

> Is array: 0

**[Additional, based on comment below]**

As the return from getUser is a string you need to cast it to an array in order to pass it to whereIN. There are two ways depending on your PHP version....

Older PHP using array() function

```
$program=DB::table('project')->whereIN('owner',array($val))->pluck('project.name','project.code')
```

PHP 5.4+ using short array syntax []

```
$program=DB::table('project')->whereIN('owner',[$val])->pluck('project.name','project.code')
```

or return an array from getUser() if that's appropriate

```
return [$reportees];
```

Comment: Its a string value

Comment: Then you need to turn it into an array before passing it to whereIN.

I've updated my answer.